# How to get a mysql connection from remote server in spring jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I am using [db4free's](http://www.db4free.net/) mysql server for my spring-webmvc project.But the problem is , I can't get a connection to the server and the Exception is

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: 
Must specify port after ':' in connection string
```

But I have specified port correctly just after ':' , Here is my configuration java class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="org.ratajo.amaderbari")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new      DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://http://www.db4free.net:3306/myDB");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("pass");

        return dataSource;
    }
```

Here is the sample program I am trying to execute

```
    MvcConfiguration mv = new MvcConfiguration();
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(mv.getDataSource());
    String sql="CREATE TABLE 'contact' ('contact_id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
    jdbcTemplate.execute(sql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url looks weird :

```
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://http://www.db4free.net:3306/myDB");
```

should be something like

```
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://www.db4free.net:3306/myDB");
```

otherwise it is trying to use http as hostname and //www.db4free.net as port. (which explains the error). But I would also double check the hostname as it looks weird to go to a host 'www.something'.

OTOH jdbc url's are weird.

Comment: Owh , thanks .. Can't believe that silly mistake there. Getting an bad sql error though.Thanks... , But how do you prefer I use the hostname ? Its the website.

Comment: better ask a different question for that with the error you get. (and format the sql, as it is no fun DDL on a single line ;-) ).

Comment: I will manage that , I was pointing what you said about the hostname ? what is wrong there?

Comment: if it works : nothing. It used to be tradition/convention that the 'www.x.y' stood for webserver host, 'mail.x.y' for the mail server, 'db.x.y' for the database server etc. This allowed sysadmins to move services around. So I am used to connect to a hostname which implies that it runs a db rather than a webserver, even when the server runs on the same hardware.